# Start named via Cron?

Tags: bash, cron, centos, named

How can I can check status of the `named` via a Cron?

And how can I start it if it is down?

Comment: What's with this question now? Why down vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what do you mean check status via cron?  what good would that do?  how to start it up depends on your version of *nix.  In Fedora/Redhat you could use `chkconfig --list | grep named` to check the status, then use `service named start` to start it up and `chkconfig on named` to have it start up at boot time.  Check the man page for `chkconfig` for more info.

---

Something like this should get it started back up for you.  Just made sure it is in root crontab as it will need root perm to start named.  Also, if you have more than one process by the name of *named*, you could run into problems with this.  One last thing, you will want to fix the scheduling part (the `* * * * *`) to run as often as you need.

```
* * * * * /bin/ps -C named > /dev/null 2>&1 || service named start
```

Comment: Actually it goes down sometimes due to server load. By the way, I'm CentOS 5.

Comment: @OhhMee, so would you be using cron just to notify you when it goes down, or would you want cron to start it back up?

Comment: I want cron to start it back again. :)

Answer (score 1):

This crontab line check every minutes that bind9 (named) process exists and send a mail if not it exists.

```
{
    crontab -l
    echo '* * * * * /usr/bin/pidof &>/dev/null named || echo "Common, bind is on fire !" | mail -s "alert: bind is down !" -- you@mymail.tld'
} | crontab -
```